# Grails 3.0.2 missing generate-views

Tags: java, grails, command-line, ide, ggts

I'm new to grails and I'm trying to get my first HelloWorld from it. I can generate it with the controller, but I can't create a view because it isn't listed in the Grails (3.0.2) list of command. Because any IDE support grails 3.*, I can't create it by that method.

In the official documentation, the commande generate-views is listed, but I can't find it anyware. I tried on several computer with Grails 3.0, 3.0.1 and 3.0.2. I got the same thing each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that dynamic scaffolding is [not yet implemented](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/6R2YaF96Uts) in Grails 3.x.

Comment: Thanks! That help me understand... But I'm reconsidering using it for my startup.

Comment: Use Grails 2.5.x. It's mature

Comment: Good idea saw303! I just began with that, and it's already a charm! Thanks guys!!